# 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value' Error while adding leveling system to bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I (unfortunately) don't have a background in coding, so I use coding blocks. I've tried using a levelling system code I got from someone, but it only worked once. But it keeps showing an error now.

## Code

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
  users = json.load(f)
  
  await update_data(users, member)
  
  with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
  
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  await bot.process_commands(message)
  if message.author.bot == False:
    with open(users.json', 'r') as f:
      users = json.load(f)
  
  
  await update_data(users, message.author)
  await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
  await level_up(users, message.author, message)
    
    
  with open(users.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(users, f)
    
    
async def update_data(users, user):
  if not f'{user.id}' in users:
    users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
    users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
    users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1
    
    
async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
  users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, message):
  experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
  lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

  if lvl_start < lvl_end:
    await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} has leveled up to level {lvl_end}')
  users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end
```

## Error

```py
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 40, in on_message
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0...
```

Not sure why it all of a sudden stopped. I (might) also need help with a code with a 'economy system' with privileges as the bot's creator. I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too experienced with Python, then I can recommend reading up on some tutorials online, such as [Automate the boring stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/). You'll be up and running in no time.

Here I've listed a few things that I've noticed in your code.

---

## Quotation marks:

First of all, you seem to be missing a couple of quotation marks:

```py
with open(users.json', 'w') as f:
```

Should be:

```py
with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
```

You can tell if/where you're missing some quotation marks, because you'll have a big block of code that's all the same colour which starts and ends with quotation marks.

---

## Indentation:

I'm not sure if this is SO's fault when you pasted in your code or what, but your indentation is also a bit funky:

```py
async def update_data(users, user):
if not f'{user.id}' in users:
users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1
```

Should instead be:

```py
async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1
```

Try some exercises on indentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) if you're not entirely familiar with it just yet.

Another example of some fixed indentation on your code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if not message.author.bot: # also edited for more pythonic use of if statements
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
```

---

## The error at hand

`JSONDecodeError` usually appears when it's reading in a badly-formatted JSON. This could happen for a multitude of reasons, but I happen to suspect that in this case it's because you tried dumping an object that didn't exist, or wasn't correctly formatted (specifically, `json.dump(users, f)`), and it closed without saving any data.

And when that happens, you end up with a `.json` that looks like this:

```
{
```

At that point, it's a good idea to delete the `.json` and start your code again - this is why making backups is so important!

If you're still unsure about any of this, I'll be happy to add some more to my answer, just leave a comment!

---

**References:**

- [Automate the boring stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/)
- [Indentation exercises/examples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp)
- [Using JSON in python](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/)
- [Discord.py Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)